# Change data type of enormous HDF5 array in python

Tags: python, large-files, hdf

I have 4 HDF5 files each around 15GB in size. Each in the form of N_i x 2048 x 7 x 7. Each of them are in float64 format. I want to merge them into a single N x 2048 x 7 x 7 dataset of type float32. I have read the h5py documentation and know that datatype of datasets can't be changed.

So the only idea I have is to

1. Convert all the files into numpy arrays.
2. Merge the arrays.
3. Convert from float64 to float32.
4. Create new dataset.

The obvious problem with this approach is that I only have 32GBs of RAM and there is no way I could fit those arrays in memory. How can I skirt around these limitations?

Comment: Can you simply work on 1% of the array at a time, do the job, write to the hdf5 file, discard the 1%, go to the next section?

Comment: I could do that in theory, do you have pointers as to how I would go about implementing that? My knowledge of the h5py library is rudimentary.

Comment: I don't know it either, but I think it's absolutely doable to append smaller datasets to an existing file (read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934724/hdf5-how-to-append-data-to-a-dataset-extensible-array)) so you should be able to initialize your file and extend if with arrays sections as you go.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I agree, try to load them as `numpy` and then change the dtype to gain some memory.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

hf = h5py.File('file.h5', 'r')
n1 = np.array(hf["dataset_name"][:])

print(n1)
```

After step 3, as you described, if your system's memory is not enough then there is no solution **in case you want to load everything at once.** You will need to find a machine with enough memory for this task.

Comment: Still 4 x 7.5 GB is dangerously close to the 32 GB limit. Given that some memory is essential for other system tasks.

Comment: these numbers do not seem right. `2048 * 10 * 10 * (8 bytes) =
0.0016384 gigabytes` each -- for float64

Comment: @makis What do you mean there is no solution? Brutally loading ALL the data in memory and see if it works is not the only way. What about working on a smaller section of the arrays and writing that to a file?

Comment: Of course I mean in case the OP wants to load everything in memory at once.

Comment: @makis it is more like 15000 * 2048 * 10 * 10 * (8 bytes)

Comment: There is no such constraint, I don't need to load everything into memory at once. I just need the stated problem solved.